# Write functions with multiple definition

Tags: equations

How to write functions with multiple defintions in LaTeX.

For example, say I want to write a function as `$f(x)=x$` when `$x>0$` and `$f(x)=0$` when `$x<=0$`.I want to write it using big curly braces write these two definitions one below another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the  `cases`environment and its mathtools  extension `cases*$ ,` dcases`and`dcases*`. For instance

```
\[f(x)=\begin{cases*}
x& when $x>0$,\\
0 & when $x\le 0$.
\end{cases*} \]
```